# how to convert pipe delimited text file to csv file in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am reading a pipe delimited text file from hdfs. I want to store this file as a dataframe for further pyspark dataframe related operations.I am able to read file from hdfs, now i want to know how to convert this into dataframe. Is it possible?

```
input=sc.textFile("hdfs://host/user/data/file1.txt") ## it is RDD
```

if it is not possible in first way, then In the second approach I want to convert this complete file into the csv format, and for this i want to replace the pipe "|" symbol by comma "," from every where and then want to store this file as csv  and after that want to convert into dataframe. Please let me know the best way to solve this issue in pyspark-2.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input=sc.textFile("hdfs://host/user/data/file1.txt") ## it is RDD
```

You can use this to convert rdd to DataFrame. We have "sc" as **SparkContext**.

## toDF()

```
input.toDF()
```

You have to infer the Schema for this and have to map or split it using '|', Instead. You can either import **HiveContext** or you can use sqlContext defined as SQLContext. By using, **sqlContext** spark will create a DataFrame for the file you specify.

```
# import
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

# Then, you can use the com.databricks.spark.csv.
df = sqlContext.read \
     .format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
     .options(header='true', delimiter='|') \
     .load('hdfs://host/user/data/file1.txt')
```

## Second Approach (after you convert to .csv), you can

```
df = sqlContext.read \
     .format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
     .options(header='true', delimiter=',') \ # you can use a ',' here
     .load('hdfs://host/user/data/file1.csv')
```

- **format()**: Specify the format you want to read the file.
- **options()**: Allow you to specify header and you can specify delimiter.
- **load()**: Loads the file for given path.

For more information, refer:

- **com.databricks.spark.csv**: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: Spark-csv and its `com.databricks.spark.csv` custom format was a temporary band-aid solution for Spark 1.x ; with Spark 2, CSV support is built-in, as in `.csv(somePath)`

Comment: If you want define a set of numbers, you can go with 1, 2, 3... or 1.0, 2.0, 3.0. It depends on the approach and implementations.

Answer (score 0):

df_with_schema = spark.read.format("csv") 
.options(header='true', delimiter='|') 
.schema(schema) 
.load("filename.csv")

instead of option try with options it will work .Same will work for sqlContext.read  also